# Coloured integers: Select outcome unexpected (part of a graph based problem using coloured vertex labels)

Tags: graphs-and-networks, style

I use the following code output and need to retrieve the position of the part containing the blue-coloured integer 4 and the part itself (Edited to indicate both are needed). The displayed code looks a bit daunting as it is given in FullForm. If you copy the code in a notebook, the output of each part will be brief and clear. I had to use FullForm due to indicate the colour selections involved.

NOTE 1: my main query regards why the proposed method does not work.
I appreciate alternative solution methods, but want to learn from mistakes. I don't see why the proposed method fails. My approach seems correct, yet gives the wrong answer. Any tips on what goes wrong would be very welcome.

Note 2: See the last two lines of this post querying why selecting on IntegerQ yields a wrong result.

Part 1:

```
List[Placed[List[
      Style[3, Rule[LineColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
       Rule[FrontFaceColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
       Rule[BackFaceColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
       Rule[GraphicsColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
       Rule[FontColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]], 
      Style[4, Rule[LineColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
       Rule[FrontFaceColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
       Rule[BackFaceColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
       Rule[GraphicsColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
       Rule[FontColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]]], List[Before, After]], Placed[
     List[Style[4, Rule[LineColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
       Rule[FrontFaceColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
       Rule[BackFaceColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
       Rule[GraphicsColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
       Rule[FontColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]], 
      Style[3, Rule[LineColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
       Rule[FrontFaceColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
       Rule[BackFaceColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
       Rule[GraphicsColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
       Rule[FontColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]]], List[Before, After]]]
```

To retrieve the expression containing the blue 4 I tried:

Part 2:

```
        Select[List[Placed[List[
              Style[3, Rule[LineColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
               Rule[FrontFaceColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
               Rule[BackFaceColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
               Rule[GraphicsColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
               Rule[FontColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]], 
              Style[4, Rule[LineColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
               Rule[FrontFaceColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
               Rule[BackFaceColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
               Rule[GraphicsColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
               Rule[FontColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]]], List[Before, After]], Placed[
             List[Style[4, Rule[LineColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
               Rule[FrontFaceColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
               Rule[BackFaceColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
               Rule[GraphicsColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
               Rule[FontColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]], 
              Style[3, Rule[LineColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
               Rule[FrontFaceColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
               Rule[BackFaceColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
               Rule[GraphicsColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
               Rule[FontColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]]], List[Before, After]]], Select[#[[1]][[2]], IntegerQ] & 
== 4]
```

Which produces { }

However

Part 3

```
 a = Placed[
    List[Style[3, Rule[LineColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
      Rule[FrontFaceColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
      Rule[BackFaceColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
      Rule[GraphicsColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
      Rule[FontColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]], 
     Style[4, Rule[LineColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
      Rule[FrontFaceColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
      Rule[BackFaceColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
      Rule[GraphicsColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
      Rule[FontColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]]], 
    List[Before, After]][[1]][[2]]

Select[a,IntegerQ]
```

produces 4 as expected.

Hence I would have expected Part 2 to produce the expression containing the blue label 4, i.e. the following result

```
Placed[List[
          Style[3, Rule[LineColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
           Rule[FrontFaceColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
           Rule[BackFaceColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
           Rule[GraphicsColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
           Rule[FontColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]], 
          Style[4, Rule[LineColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
           Rule[FrontFaceColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
           Rule[BackFaceColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
           Rule[GraphicsColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
           Rule[FontColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]]], List[Before, After]]
```

On closer inspection I tried the following:

```
FullForm[Select[a, IntegerQ]]
```

which results in

```
Style[4]
```

However, Style[4] should not be the result of a selection for integers.

**What is going on?**

*Note that*

```
IntegerQ[Style[4]]
```

*yields False.*

*Yet Style[4] is what is being produced by FullForm[Select[a, IntegerQ]].*

**Can you clarify why this is the case?**

**Is this a bug?** Or am I missing something?

Comment: I am confused by your problem. Do you want the position of the blue 4, or the expression that generates the blue 4, or something else?

Comment: Actually, both. I will amend in an edit

Comment: Edited it accordingly

Comment: `LineColor`, `FrontFaceColor`, `BackFaceColor` and `GraphicsColor` are not options for `Style`. Your code could be written `{Placed[{Style[3, FontColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], Style[4, FontColor -> RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]}, {Before, After}], Placed[{Style[4, FontColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], Style[3, FontColor -> RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]}, {Before, After}]}`

Comment: @BenyIzd I did not choose this format. It is Mathematica output, i.e generated by Mathematica code beyond my control. Not sure if you are saying that the code should not be written this way or that the wrong output I indicate in the post is due to my handling LineColor etc in a wrong way?

Comment: @Mike Could you show the code that generates the output you are working with? It might be easier to tackle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does the above example result in: `Style[4]`?

Consider the example:

```
Select[{c0,c1},#==c0&]

(* { c0 } *)
```

No problem here. Now we replace "{..}" by "f[..]":

```
Select[f[c0, c1], # == c0 &]

(* f[c0] *)
```

Therefore, the head of the expression is retained. Now, consider:

```
a // FullForm
```

[image]

`a` has a head of `Style` and a first element of `4`. Therefore:

```
Select[a, IntegerQ] // FullForm
```

will pick out `4` and wrap it with the header `Style`: `Style[4]`

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that is very clear. I misinterpreted select to return the selected element for lists. I understand the motivation to retain the head to deal with the case of returning several elements satisfying the condition.

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = List[
  Placed[List[
    Style[3, Rule[LineColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
     Rule[FrontFaceColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
     Rule[BackFaceColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
     Rule[GraphicsColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
     Rule[FontColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]], 
    Style[4, Rule[LineColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
     Rule[FrontFaceColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
     Rule[BackFaceColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
     Rule[GraphicsColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
     Rule[FontColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]]], List[Before, After]], 
  Placed[List[
    Style[4, Rule[LineColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
     Rule[FrontFaceColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
     Rule[BackFaceColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
     Rule[GraphicsColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
     Rule[FontColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]], 
    Style[3, Rule[LineColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
     Rule[FrontFaceColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
     Rule[BackFaceColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
     Rule[GraphicsColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
     Rule[FontColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]]], List[Before, After]]]
```

Finding the element with the blue 4:

```
Select[lst, 
 MemberQ[#[[1]], 
   Style[4, Rule[LineColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
    Rule[FrontFaceColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
    Rule[BackFaceColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
    Rule[GraphicsColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
    Rule[FontColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]]] &]
```

[image]

The position of the element that contains the blue 4:

```
Position[lst, 
 Style[4, Rule[LineColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
  Rule[FrontFaceColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
  Rule[BackFaceColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
  Rule[GraphicsColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
  Rule[FontColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]]]

(* {{1, 1, 2}} *)

lst[[1,1,2]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are asking how to determine the position of the blue 4.

Your problem comes from the fact that pattern are also evaluated and that the output for presentation does not always show the underlying code.

Your list reads:

```
li=li = List[
  Placed[List[
    Style[3, Rule[LineColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
     Rule[FrontFaceColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
     Rule[BackFaceColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
     Rule[GraphicsColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
     Rule[FontColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]], 
    Style[4, Rule[LineColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
     Rule[FrontFaceColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
     Rule[BackFaceColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
     Rule[GraphicsColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
     Rule[FontColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]]], List[Before, After]], 
  Placed[List[
    Style[4, Rule[LineColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
     Rule[FrontFaceColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
     Rule[BackFaceColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
     Rule[GraphicsColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
     Rule[FontColor, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]], 
    Style[3, Rule[LineColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
     Rule[FrontFaceColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
     Rule[BackFaceColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
     Rule[GraphicsColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
     Rule[FontColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]]], List[Before, After]]]
```

And we want to determine the positions of terms with a pattern:

```
pat = Style[n_, Rule[LineColor, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], __];
Position[li, pat, Infinity] 

(* {{1, 1, 2}} *)
```

However, pay attention. If we now look at:

```
li[[1, 1, 2]]
(* 4 *)
```

this looks unsuspicious like the integer 4. But look at:

li[[1, 1, 2]] //FullForm

we get:

[image]

not exactly what we need for further calculations. Therefore to get the integer 4 we need an additional level:

```
li[[1, 1, 2, 1]]
(* 4 *)
```

Therefore, the real position is:

```
{1, 1, 2, 1}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get this part, i.e. the fact that a blue 4 looks like a 4 but is a different expression. I don't see why IntegerQ (in my approach) would yield the seemingly wrong result Style[4].